# 2кб текста разбить на случайные 4-6 абзацев

Tags: алгоритм, php

На входе строчка с текстом 2-5 кб, обычным текстом, литературным, русским.
Этот текст надо просто раздробить на абзацы, длиной от 300-700 байт.

Как подползти к решению ?

Раздробить, значит вставить перевод строки.

Answer (score 2):

посимвольное считывание(т.е. по одному байту) ($x= fread($fp,1)) увеличение счётчика ($i++), проверка на точку и на количество символов после последнего перевода(if($x=="." && $i<=700 && $i>=300)) добавляем в файл перевод (fwrite($fp1,"n")), а так просто копируем в файл (fwrite($fp1,$x)) и это всё в цикле, примерно так:

```
$fp = fopen("1.txt","r");  
$fp1 = fopen("2.txt","w");  
$i = 0;  
while ($x = fread($fp,1))  
{  
  $i++;  
  fwrite($fp1,$x);  
  if($x=="." && $i<=700 && $i>=300)  
  {  
      fwrite($fp1,"\n");  
      $x = 0;

  }

}  
fclose($fp);  
fclose($fp1);
```

потом удалить 1.txt и переименовать 2.txt в 1.txt или также как и сверху побайтово или больше скопировать 2.txt в 1.txt и удалить 2.txt...или пусть остаётся, если много раз надо так делать))))

Comment: если текст не в файле, то работа со строками, а так всё то же самое ток цикл конца строки будет а не конца файла

Comment: да, ещё проверку на ! и на ? кроме точки можно сделать, хотя по идее и точки хватит

Comment: Единственная ошибка в вашем коде - это строчка
"if($x=="." && $i<=700 && $i>=300)". А вот вдруг точка не встретится даже через 701 байт, то ваш цикл впадет в бесконечную итерацию.
Правильнее сделать так:
"if($x=="." && $i>=300)"

Comment: ну да, в принципе, правда цикл не будет бесконечным, он идёт, пока можно читать из файла, а так согласен про условие))